# NBA*: Very efficient bidirectional heuristic search algorithm in Java - follow-up

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, pathfinding, a-star

This post elaborates on [NBA*: Very efficient bidirectional heuristic search algorithm in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143527/nba-very-efficient-bidirectional-heuristic-search-algorithm-in-java).

I have made the following changes:

1. Added an explicit type for representing digraph paths: `DirectedGraphPath`.
2. If the target node is unreachable from the source node, a `TargetUnreachableException` is thrown instead of returning a sentinel value representing a nonexistent path.
3. `HeapEntry` removed from `AbstractPathfinder` and moved into the package `net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.support`, where it is declared as package-private.
4. `ZeroHeuristicFunction` is removed and a lambda is used instead.
5. `HeuristicFunction` is annotated as `@FunctionalInterface`.
6. The source and target nodes in the demonstration are chosen to be as far from each other as feasible.
7. Minor improvements in the `Demo`.
8. An optimality related bug fixed.

**NBAStarPathfinder.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.support;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Set;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraph;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraphWeightFunction;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.AbstractPathfinder;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.DirectedGraphPath;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.HeuristicFunction;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.TargetUnreachableException;

/**
 * This pathfinding algorithm is due to Wim Pijls and Henk Post in "Yet another
 * bidirectional algorithm for shortest paths." 15 June 2009.
 * <p>
 * <b>This class is not thread-safe.</b> If you need it in different threads,
 * make sure each thread has its own object of this class.
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.61 (Oct 13, 2016)
 */
public final class NBAStarPathfinder extends AbstractPathfinder {

    private final HeuristicFunction heuristicFunction;
    private final PriorityQueue<HeapEntry> OPENA = new PriorityQueue<>();
    private final PriorityQueue<HeapEntry> OPENB = new PriorityQueue<>();
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> PARENTSA = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> PARENTSB = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<Integer, Double> DISTANCEA = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<Integer, Double> DISTANCEB = new HashMap<>();
    private final Set<Integer> CLOSED = new HashSet<>();

    private double fA;
    private double fB;
    private double bestPathLength;
    private Integer touchNode;
    private Integer sourceNode;
    private Integer targetNode;

    public NBAStarPathfinder(DirectedGraph graph,
            DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction,
            HeuristicFunction heuristicFunction) {
        super(graph, weightFunction);
        this.heuristicFunction
                = Objects.requireNonNull(heuristicFunction,
                        "The input heuristic function is null.");
    }

    @Override
    public DirectedGraphPath search(int sourceNode, int targetNode) {
        if (sourceNode == targetNode) {
            return new DirectedGraphPath(Arrays.asList(sourceNode));
        }

        init(sourceNode, targetNode);

        while (!OPENA.isEmpty() && !OPENB.isEmpty()) {
            if (OPENA.size() < OPENB.size()) {
                expandInForwardDirection();
            } else {
                expandInBackwardDirection();
            }
        }

        if (touchNode == null) {
            throw new TargetUnreachableException(graph, 
                                                 sourceNode,
                                                 targetNode);
        }

        return tracebackPath(touchNode, PARENTSA, PARENTSB);
    }

    private void expandInForwardDirection() {
        Integer currentNode = OPENA.remove().getNode();

        if (CLOSED.contains(currentNode)) {
            return;
        }

        CLOSED.add(currentNode);

        if (DISTANCEA.get(currentNode) +
                heuristicFunction.estimateDistanceBetween(currentNode,
                                                          targetNode)
                >= bestPathLength
                ||
                DISTANCEA.get(currentNode) +
                fB - 
                heuristicFunction.estimateDistanceBetween(currentNode,
                                                          sourceNode)
                >= bestPathLength) {
            // Reject the 'currentNode'.
        } else {
            // Stabilize the 'currentNode'.
            for (Integer childNode : graph.getChildrenOf(currentNode)) {
                if (CLOSED.contains(childNode)) {
                    continue;
                }

                double tentativeDistance
                        = DISTANCEA.get(currentNode)
                        + weightFunction.get(currentNode, childNode);

                if (!DISTANCEA.containsKey(childNode)
                        || 
                        DISTANCEA.get(childNode) > tentativeDistance) {
                    DISTANCEA.put(childNode, tentativeDistance);
                    PARENTSA.put(childNode, currentNode);
                    HeapEntry e
                            = new HeapEntry(
                                    childNode,
                                    tentativeDistance
                                    + heuristicFunction
                                    .estimateDistanceBetween(childNode,
                                                             targetNode));
                    OPENA.add(e);

                    if (DISTANCEB.containsKey(childNode)) {
                        double pathLength = tentativeDistance
                                + DISTANCEB.get(childNode);

                        if (bestPathLength > pathLength) {
                            bestPathLength = pathLength;
                            touchNode = childNode;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!OPENA.isEmpty()) {
            fA = OPENA.peek().getDistance();
        }
    }

    private void expandInBackwardDirection() {
        Integer currentNode = OPENB.remove().getNode();

        if (CLOSED.contains(currentNode)) {
            return;
        }

        CLOSED.add(currentNode);

        if (DISTANCEB.get(currentNode) +
                heuristicFunction.estimateDistanceBetween(currentNode,
                                                          sourceNode)
                >= bestPathLength
                || 
                DISTANCEB.get(currentNode) +
                fA -
                heuristicFunction.estimateDistanceBetween(currentNode, 
                                                          targetNode)
                >= bestPathLength) {
            // Reject the node 'currentNode'.
        } else {
            for (Integer parentNode : graph.getParentsOf(currentNode)) {
                if (CLOSED.contains(parentNode)) {
                    continue;
                }

                double tentativeDistance
                        = DISTANCEB.get(currentNode)
                        + weightFunction.get(parentNode, currentNode);

                if (!DISTANCEB.containsKey(parentNode)
                        ||
                        DISTANCEB.get(parentNode) > tentativeDistance) {
                    DISTANCEB.put(parentNode, tentativeDistance);
                    PARENTSB.put(parentNode, currentNode);
                    HeapEntry e
                            = new HeapEntry(parentNode,
                                    tentativeDistance
                                    + heuristicFunction
                                    .estimateDistanceBetween(parentNode,
                                                             sourceNode));
                    OPENB.add(e);

                    if (DISTANCEA.containsKey(parentNode)) {
                        double pathLength = tentativeDistance
                                + DISTANCEA.get(parentNode);

                        if (bestPathLength > pathLength) {
                            bestPathLength = pathLength;
                            touchNode = parentNode;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!OPENB.isEmpty()) {
            fB = OPENB.peek().getDistance();
        }
    }

    private void init(Integer sourceNode, Integer targetNode) {
        OPENA.clear();
        OPENB.clear();
        PARENTSA.clear();
        PARENTSB.clear();
        DISTANCEA.clear();
        DISTANCEB.clear();
        CLOSED.clear();

        double totalDistance
                = heuristicFunction.estimateDistanceBetween(sourceNode,
                                                            targetNode);

        fA = totalDistance;
        fB = totalDistance;
        bestPathLength = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        touchNode = null;
        this.sourceNode = sourceNode;
        this.targetNode = targetNode;

        OPENA.add(new HeapEntry(sourceNode, fA));
        OPENB.add(new HeapEntry(targetNode, fB));
        PARENTSA.put(sourceNode, null);
        PARENTSB.put(targetNode, null);
        DISTANCEA.put(sourceNode, 0.0);
        DISTANCEB.put(targetNode, 0.0);
    }
}
```

**AStarPathfinder.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.support;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Set;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraph;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraphWeightFunction;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.AbstractPathfinder;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.DirectedGraphPath;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.HeuristicFunction;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.TargetUnreachableException;

public final class AStarPathfinder extends AbstractPathfinder {

    private final HeuristicFunction heuristicFunction;
    private final PriorityQueue<HeapEntry> OPEN = new PriorityQueue<>();
    private final Set<Integer> CLOSED = new HashSet<>();
    private final Map<Integer, Double> DISTANCE = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> PARENTS = new HashMap<>();

    public AStarPathfinder(DirectedGraph graph,
                           DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction,
                           HeuristicFunction heuristicFunction) {
        super(graph, weightFunction);
        this.heuristicFunction = 
                Objects.requireNonNull(heuristicFunction,
                                       "The input heuristic function is null.");
    }

    @Override
    public DirectedGraphPath search(int sourceNodeId, int targetNodeId) {
        init(sourceNodeId);

        while (!OPEN.isEmpty()) {
            Integer currentNodeId = OPEN.remove().getNode();

            if (currentNodeId.equals(targetNodeId)) {
                return tracebackPath(currentNodeId, PARENTS);
            }

            if (CLOSED.contains(currentNodeId)) {
                continue;
            }

            CLOSED.add(currentNodeId);

            for (Integer childNodeId : graph.getChildrenOf(currentNodeId)) {
                if (CLOSED.contains(childNodeId)) {
                    continue;
                }

                double tentativeDistance = 
                        DISTANCE.get(currentNodeId) +
                        weightFunction.get(currentNodeId, childNodeId);

                if (!DISTANCE.containsKey(childNodeId)
                        || DISTANCE.get(childNodeId) > tentativeDistance) {
                    DISTANCE.put(childNodeId, tentativeDistance);
                    PARENTS.put(childNodeId, currentNodeId);
                    OPEN.add(
                        new HeapEntry(
                            childNodeId, 
                            tentativeDistance +
                            heuristicFunction
                                    .estimateDistanceBetween(childNodeId, 
                                                             targetNodeId)));
                }
            }
        }

        throw new TargetUnreachableException(graph, sourceNodeId, targetNodeId);
    }

    private void init(int sourceNodeId) {
        OPEN.clear();
        CLOSED.clear();
        PARENTS.clear();
        DISTANCE.clear();

        OPEN.add(new HeapEntry(sourceNodeId, 0.0));
        PARENTS.put(sourceNodeId, null);
        DISTANCE.put(sourceNodeId, 0.0);
    }
}
```

**DijkstraPathfinder.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.support;

import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraph;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraphWeightFunction;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.AbstractPathfinder;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.DirectedGraphPath;

public final class DijkstraPathfinder extends AbstractPathfinder {

    private final AStarPathfinder finderImplementation;

    public DijkstraPathfinder(DirectedGraph graph,
                              DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction) {
        this.finderImplementation = 
                new AStarPathfinder(graph, 
                                    weightFunction,
                                    (a, b) -> { return 0.0; });
    }

    @Override
    public DirectedGraphPath search(int sourceNodeId, int targetNodeId) {
        return finderImplementation.search(sourceNodeId, targetNodeId);
    }
}
```

**HeapEntry.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.support;

/**
 * This class implements an entry for {@link java.util.PriorityQueue}.
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Oct 13, 2016)
 */
final class HeapEntry implements Comparable<HeapEntry> {

    private final int nodeId;
    private final double distance; // The priority key.

    public HeapEntry(int nodeId, double distance) {
        this.nodeId = nodeId;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public int getNode() {
        return nodeId;
    }

    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(HeapEntry o) {
        return Double.compare(distance, o.distance);
    }
}
```

**EuclideanHeuristicFunction.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.support;

import java.util.Objects;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.DirectedGraphNodeCoordinates;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.HeuristicFunction;

/**
 * This class implements a heuristic function that returns the Euclidean
 * distance between two given nodes.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Oct 6, 2016)
 */
public class EuclideanHeuristicFunction implements HeuristicFunction {

    private final DirectedGraphNodeCoordinates coordinates;

    public EuclideanHeuristicFunction(DirectedGraphNodeCoordinates coordinates) {
        this.coordinates =
                Objects.requireNonNull(coordinates,
                                       "The input coordinate map is null.");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    public double estimateDistanceBetween(int nodeId1, int nodeId2) {
        return coordinates.get(nodeId1).distance(coordinates.get(nodeId2));
    }
}
```

**HeuristicFunction.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding;

/**
 * This interface defines the API for heuristic functions used in pathfinding.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Oct 6, 2016)
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface HeuristicFunction {

    /**
     * Provides an optimistic (underestimated) distance between {@code nodeId1}
     * and {@code nodeId2} using a specific distance metric.
     * 
     * @param nodeId1 the first node.
     * @param nodeId2 the second node.
     * @return a shortest path estimate between the two input nodes.
     */
    public double estimateDistanceBetween(int nodeId1, int nodeId2);
}
```

**TargetUnreachableException.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding;

import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraph;

public class TargetUnreachableException extends RuntimeException {

    private final DirectedGraph graph;
    private final Integer sourceNode;
    private final Integer targetNode;

    public TargetUnreachableException(DirectedGraph graph,
                                      Integer sourceNode,
                                      Integer targetNode) {
        this.graph = graph;
        this.sourceNode = sourceNode;
        this.targetNode = targetNode;
    }

    public DirectedGraph getGraph() {
        return graph;
    }

    public int getSourceNode() {
        return sourceNode;
    }

    public int getTargetNode() {
        return targetNode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "'" + targetNode + "' is not reachable from '" 
                   + sourceNode + "'.";
    }
}
```

**DirectedGraphPath.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraphWeightFunction;

/**
 * This class implements a type for representing paths in directed graphs.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Oct 16, 2016)
 */
public final class DirectedGraphPath {

    /**
     * The actual list of nodes on a path.
     */
    private final List<Integer> path;

    public DirectedGraphPath(List<Integer> path) {
        checkNotEmpty(path);
        this.path = new ArrayList<>(path);
    }

    public int getNode(int index) {
        return path.get(index);
    }

    public int getNumberOfNodes() {
        return path.size();
    }

    public int getNumberOfEdges() {
        return path.size() - 1;
    }

    public double getCost(DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction) {
        double cost = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < path.size() - 1; ++i) {
            cost += weightFunction.get(path.get(i), path.get(i + 1));
        }

        return cost;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }

        if (o == null || !o.getClass().equals(getClass())) {
            return false;
        }

        return path.equals(((DirectedGraphPath) o).path);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
        String separator = "";

        for (Integer node : path) {
            sb.append(separator).append(node);
            separator = ", ";
        }

        return sb.append(']').toString();
    }

    private void checkNotEmpty(List<Integer> path) {
        if (path.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The input path is not allowed to be empty.");
        }
    }
}
```

**DirectedGraphNodeCoordinates.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * This class allows mapping each graph node to its coordinates on a 
 * two-dimensional plane.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Oct 6, 2016)
 */
public class DirectedGraphNodeCoordinates {

    /**
     * Maps each node to its coordinates.
     */
    private final Map<Integer, Point2D.Double> map = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Associates the coordinates {@code point} to the node {@code nodeId}.
     * 
     * @param nodeId the node to map.
     * @param point  the coordinates to associate to the node.
     */
    public void put(int nodeId, Point2D.Double point) {
        map.put(nodeId, point);
    }

    /**
     * Return the point of the input node.
     * 
     * @param nodeId the node whose coordinates to return.
     * @return the coordinates.
     */
    public Point2D.Double get(int nodeId) {
        return map.get(nodeId);
    }
}
```

**AbstractPathfinder.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraph;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraphWeightFunction;

/**
 * This abstract class defines some facilities shared by pathfinding algorithms
 * and API for using them.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Oct 6, 2016)
 */
public abstract class AbstractPathfinder {

    /**
     * The graph to search in.
     */
    protected final DirectedGraph graph;

    /**
     * The weight function to use.
     */
    protected final DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction;

    protected AbstractPathfinder(DirectedGraph graph,
                                 DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction) {
        this.graph = Objects.requireNonNull(graph, "The input graph is null.");
        this.weightFunction =
                Objects.requireNonNull(weightFunction,
                                       "The input weight function is null.");
    }

    protected AbstractPathfinder() {
        this.graph = null;
        this.weightFunction = null; // Compiler requires this initialization.
    }

    /**
     * Searches and returns a shortest path starting from the node 
     * {@code sourceNodeId} and leading to {@code targetNodeId}.
     * 
     * @param sourceNodeId the source node.
     * @param targetNodeId the target node.
     * @return a shortest path of nodes from source node to target node
     *         including the terminal nodes.
     */
    public abstract DirectedGraphPath search(int sourceNodeId,
                                             int targetNodeId);

    /**
     * Reconstructs a shortest path from the data structures maintained by a 
     * <b>bidirectional</b> pathfinding algorithm.
     * 
     * @param touchNodeId the node where the two search frontiers agree.
     * @param PARENTSA the parent map in the forward search direction.
     * @param PARENTSB the parent map in the backward search direction.
     * @return the shortest path object.
     */
    protected DirectedGraphPath tracebackPath(int touchNodeId, 
                                              Map<Integer, Integer> PARENTSA,
                                              Map<Integer, Integer> PARENTSB) {
        List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer currentNodeId = touchNodeId;

        while (currentNodeId != null) {
            path.add(currentNodeId);
            currentNodeId = PARENTSA.get(currentNodeId);
        }

        Collections.<Integer>reverse(path);

        if (PARENTSB != null) {
            currentNodeId = PARENTSB.get(touchNodeId);

            while (currentNodeId != null) {
                path.add(currentNodeId);
                currentNodeId = PARENTSB.get(currentNodeId);
            }
        }

        return new DirectedGraphPath(path);
    }

    /**
     * Reconstructs a shortest path from the data structures maintained by a
     * unidirectional pathfinding algorithm.
     * 
     * @param targetNodeId the target node.
     * @param PARENTS      the parents map.
     * @return the shortest path object
     */
    protected DirectedGraphPath tracebackPath(int targetNodeId, 
                                              Map<Integer, Integer> PARENTS) {
        return tracebackPath(targetNodeId, PARENTS, null);
    }
}
```

**DirectedGraph.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class implements a directed graph data structure via adjacency lists. 
 * This implementation represents each graph node as an unique integer.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.61 (Oct 13, 2016)
 */
public class DirectedGraph {

    /**
     * This map maps each directed graph node to the list of its child nodes.
     */
    private final Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> childMap  = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * This map maps each directed graph node to the list of its parent nodes.
     */
    private final Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> parentMap = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Adds a new node represented by integer {@code nodeId} to this graph if
     * it is not yet present in it.
     * 
     * @param nodeId the node to add.
     */
    public void addNode(int nodeId) {
        childMap .putIfAbsent(nodeId, new HashSet<>());
        parentMap.putIfAbsent(nodeId, new HashSet<>());
    }

    /**
     * Creates a directed arc <tt>(tailNodeId, headNodeId)</tt> if it is not yet
     * present in the graph.
     * 
     * @param tailNodeId the tail node of the arc.
     * @param headNodeId the head node of the arc.
     */
    public void addArc(int tailNodeId, int headNodeId) {
        childMap .get(tailNodeId).add(headNodeId);
        parentMap.get(headNodeId).add(tailNodeId);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the view of all the nodes in this graph.
     * 
     * @return the set of all nodes.
     */
    public Set<Integer> getNodeSet() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(childMap.keySet());
    }

    /**
     * Returns the set of all child nodes of the given node {@code nodeId}.
     * 
     * @param nodeId the node whose children to return.
     * @return the set of child nodes of {@code nodeId}.
     */
    public Set<Integer> getChildrenOf(int nodeId) {
        return Collections.<Integer>unmodifiableSet(childMap.get(nodeId));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the set of all parent nodes of the given node {@code nodeId}.
     * 
     * @param nodeId the node whose parents to return.
     * @return the set of parent nodes of {@code nodeId}.
     */
    public Set<Integer> getParentsOf(int nodeId) {
        return Collections.<Integer>unmodifiableSet(parentMap.get(nodeId));
    }
}
```

**DirectedGraphWeightFunction.java**

```
package net.coderodde.graph;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * This class maps directed arcs to their weights. An arc weight is not allowed
 * to be a <tt>NaN</tt> value or negative.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @vesion 1.6 (Oct 6, 2016)
 */
public class DirectedGraphWeightFunction {

    /**
     * Maps the arcs to the arc weights.
     */
    private final Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> map = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Associates the weight {@code weight} with the arc 
     * <tt>(tailNodeId, headNodeId)</tt>.
     * 
     * @param tailNodeId the starting node of the arc.
     * @param headNodeId the ending node of the arc.
     * @param weight the arc weight.
     */
    public void put(int tailNodeId, int headNodeId, double weight) {
        checkWeight(weight);
        map.putIfAbsent(tailNodeId, new HashMap<>());
        map.get(tailNodeId).put(headNodeId, weight);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the weight of the given arc.
     * 
     * @param tailNodeId the starting node (tail node) of the arc.
     * @param headNodeId the ending node (head node) of the arc.
     * @return 
     */
    public double get(int tailNodeId, int headNodeId) {
        return map.get(tailNodeId).get(headNodeId);
    }

    private void checkWeight(double weight) {
        if (Double.isNaN(weight)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input weight is NaN.");
        }

        if (weight < 0.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The input weight is negative: " + weight + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraph;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraphWeightFunction;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.AbstractPathfinder;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.DirectedGraphNodeCoordinates;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.DirectedGraphPath;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.HeuristicFunction;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.support.AStarPathfinder;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.support.DijkstraPathfinder;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.support.EuclideanHeuristicFunction;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.support.NBAStarPathfinder;

/**
 * This class contains a demonstration program comparing performance of three
 * point-to-point shortest path algorithms:
 * <ol>
 *  <li>A*,</li>
 *  <li>Dijkstra's algorithm</li>
 *  <li>NBA*, New Bidirectional A*.</li>
 * </ol>
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.61 (Oct 16, 2016)
 */
public class Demo {

    private static final int NODES = 100_000;
    private static final int ARCS =  500_000;
    private static final double PLANE_WIDTH = 1000.0;
    private static final double PLANE_HEIGHT = 1000.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long seed = System.nanoTime();
        Random random = new Random(seed);
        System.out.println("Seed = " + seed);

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        DirectedGraph graph = getRandomGraph(NODES, ARCS, random);
        DirectedGraphNodeCoordinates coordinates = getCoordinates(graph,
                                                                  PLANE_WIDTH,
                                                                  PLANE_HEIGHT,
                                                                  random);
        DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction = 
                getWeightFunction(graph, coordinates);

        Integer sourceNodeId = getSource(graph, coordinates);
        Integer targetNodeId = getTarget(graph, coordinates);

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Created the graph data structures in " +
                           (end - start) + " milliseconds.");

        System.out.println("Source: " + sourceNodeId);
        System.out.println("Target: " + targetNodeId);
        System.out.println();

        HeuristicFunction hf = new EuclideanHeuristicFunction(coordinates);

        AbstractPathfinder finder1 = new AStarPathfinder(graph,
                                                         weightFunction,
                                                         hf);

        AbstractPathfinder finder2 = new DijkstraPathfinder(graph,
                                                            weightFunction);

        AbstractPathfinder finder3 = new NBAStarPathfinder(graph, 
                                                           weightFunction,
                                                           hf);
        DirectedGraphPath path1 = benchmark(finder1,
                                            sourceNodeId, 
                                            targetNodeId);

        DirectedGraphPath path2 = benchmark(finder2, 
                                            sourceNodeId,
                                            targetNodeId);

        DirectedGraphPath path3 = benchmark(finder3, 
                                            sourceNodeId, 
                                            targetNodeId);

        boolean agreed = path1.equals(path2) && path1.equals(path3);

        if (agreed) {
            System.out.println("Algorithms agree: true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Algorithms DISAGREED!");
            System.out.println("A* path length:       " 
                    + path1.getCost(weightFunction));
            System.out.println("Dijkstra path length: " 
                    + path2.getCost(weightFunction));
            System.out.println("NBA* path length:     " 
                    + path3.getCost(weightFunction));
        }
    }

    private static DirectedGraphPath benchmark(AbstractPathfinder pathfinder,
                                               int sourceNode, 
                                               int targetNode) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        DirectedGraphPath path = pathfinder.search(sourceNode, targetNode);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(pathfinder.getClass().getSimpleName() + 
                           " in " + (end - start) + " milliseconds.");
        System.out.println(path);
        System.out.println();
        return path;
    }

    private static DirectedGraph getRandomGraph(int nodes, 
                                                int arcs, 
                                                Random random) {
        DirectedGraph graph = new DirectedGraph();

        for (int id = 0; id < nodes; ++id) {
            graph.addNode(id);
        }

        List<Integer> graphNodeList = new ArrayList<>(graph.getNodeSet());

        while (arcs-- > 0) {
            Integer tailNodeId = choose(graphNodeList, random);
            Integer headNodeId = choose(graphNodeList, random);
            graph.addArc(tailNodeId, headNodeId);
        }

        return graph;
    }

    private static DirectedGraphNodeCoordinates 
        getCoordinates(DirectedGraph graph, 
                       double planeWidth,
                       double planeHeight,
                       Random random) {
        DirectedGraphNodeCoordinates coordinates =
                new DirectedGraphNodeCoordinates();

        for (Integer nodeId : graph.getNodeSet()) {
            coordinates.put(nodeId, 
                            randomPoint(planeWidth, planeHeight, random));
        }

        return coordinates;
    }

    private static DirectedGraphWeightFunction 
        getWeightFunction(DirectedGraph graph,
                          DirectedGraphNodeCoordinates coordinates) {
        DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction = 
                new DirectedGraphWeightFunction();

        for (Integer nodeId : graph.getNodeSet()) {
            Point2D.Double p1 = coordinates.get(nodeId);

            for (Integer childNodeId : graph.getChildrenOf(nodeId)) {
                Point2D.Double p2 = coordinates.get(childNodeId);
                double distance = p1.distance(p2);
                weightFunction.put(nodeId, childNodeId, 1.2 * distance);
            }
        }

        return weightFunction;
    }

    private static Point2D.Double randomPoint(double width,
                                              double height,
                                              Random random) {
        return new Point2D.Double(width * random.nextDouble(),
                                  height * random.nextDouble());
    }

    private static <T> T choose(List<T> list, Random random) {
        return list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
    }

    private static Integer
         getClosestTo(DirectedGraph graph,
                      DirectedGraphNodeCoordinates coordinates,
                      Point2D.Double point) {
        double bestDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        Integer bestNode = null;

        for (Integer node : graph.getNodeSet()) {
            Point2D.Double nodePoint = coordinates.get(node);

            if (bestDistance > nodePoint.distance(point)) {
                bestDistance = nodePoint.distance(point);
                bestNode = node;
            }
        }

        return bestNode;
    }

    private static Integer getSource(DirectedGraph graph,
                                     DirectedGraphNodeCoordinates coordinates) {
        return getClosestTo(graph, coordinates, new Point2D.Double());
    }

    private static Integer getTarget(DirectedGraph graph,
                                     DirectedGraphNodeCoordinates coordinates) {
        return getClosestTo(graph, 
                            coordinates,
                            new Point2D.Double(PLANE_WIDTH, PLANE_HEIGHT));
    }
}
```

**Performance figures**

A typical run of the demonstration might output something like this:

> ```
> Seed = 380420829228515
> Created the graph data structures in 6350 milliseconds.
> Source: 58350
> Target: 45998
>
> AStarPathfinder in 996 milliseconds.
> [58350, 69183, 24066, 12240, 79684, 33326, 53655, 74615, 97690, 28336, 45998]
>
> DijkstraPathfinder in 5025 milliseconds.
> [58350, 69183, 24066, 12240, 79684, 33326, 53655, 74615, 97690, 28336, 45998]
>
> NBAStarPathfinder in 29 milliseconds.
> [58350, 69183, 24066, 12240, 79684, 33326, 53655, 74615, 97690, 28336, 45998]
>
> Algorithms agree: true
> ```

**Critique request**

I would like to hear anything you can tell me, especially:

- API design
- Modularity
- Naming
- Coding conventions
- Efficiency
- Javadoc

Answer (score 2):

`NBAStarPathfinder`:

- What is the difference between the `A`s and `B`s? Names should be more descriptive.
- `fB` needs a new name.  Unless it's referring to Facebook, which I doubt very much.
- `expandIn___Direction`: A method should do one thing and do it well.  Break this up.  (You may even find some duplicate code in the process.)
- `// Stabilize the 'currentNode'.` - rather than that being a comment, make it a method with such a name.

`AbstractPathFinder`:

- Will this even work if the default constructor is called? If not, can we get rid of it?

`DirectedGraphWeightFunction`:

- `checkWeight` is checking what?  That it's valid?  This should be renamed accordingly.

That's just at a quick glance for you.