# Performance Enhancement of A Star Path Finder algorithm with 1024 multidimentional array

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, pathfinding, a-star

I have the below code for a A* pathfinder, however it is taking upwards of 10 minutes to find a solution using a simple 1024 x 1024 array.

I had to comment out `//Collections.sort(this.openList);` as it was throwing a `comparison method violates its general contract!` error when running.

Is the algorithm correct and any idea why the bottleneck? Some people using C++ are getting a response time of 40ms, not 10+ mins!

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

class AStarPathfinding {

    // Closed list, open list and calculatedPath lists
    private final List<Node> openList;
    private final List<Node> closedList;
    private final List<Node> calcPath;

    // Collision Map to store tha map in
    private final int[][] collisionMap;

    // Current node the  program is executing
    private Node currentNode;

    // Define the start and end coords
    private final int xstart;
    private final int ystart;
    private int xEnd, yEnd;

    // Node class for convenience
    static class Node implements Comparable {
        public Node parent;
        public int x, y;
        public double g;
        public double h;
        Node(Node parent, int xpos, int ypos, double g, double h) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.x = xpos;
            this.y = ypos;
            this.g = g;
            this.h = h;
       }

       // Compare f value (g + h)
       @Override
       public int compareTo(Object o) {
           Node that = (Node) o;
           return (int)((this.g + this.h) - (that.g + that.h));
       }
   }

    // construct and initialise 
    AStarPathfinding(int[][] collisionMap, int xstart, int ystart) {
        this.openList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.closedList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.calcPath = new ArrayList<>();
        this.collisionMap = collisionMap;
        this.currentNode = new Node(null, xstart, ystart, 0, 0);
        this.xstart = xstart;
        this.ystart = ystart;

    }

    // returns a List<> of nodes to target
    public List<Node> findPathTo(int xTo, int yTo) {

        this.xEnd = xTo;
        this.yEnd = yTo;

        // Add this to the closed list
        this.closedList.add(this.currentNode);

        // Add neighbours to openList for iteration
        addNeigborsToOpenList();

        // Whilst not at our target
        while (this.currentNode.x != this.xEnd || this.currentNode.y != this.yEnd) {

            // If nothing in the open list then return with null - handled in error message in main calling func
            if (this.openList.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }

            // get the lowest f value and add it to the closed list, f calculated when neighbours are sorted
            this.currentNode = this.openList.get(0);
            this.openList.remove(0); 
            this.closedList.add(this.currentNode); 

            addNeigborsToOpenList();

        }

        // add this node to the calculated path
        this.calcPath.add(0, this.currentNode);

        while (this.currentNode.x != this.xstart || this.currentNode.y != this.ystart) {

            this.currentNode = this.currentNode.parent;

            this.calcPath.add(0, this.currentNode);

        }

        return this.calcPath;
    }



    // Searches the current list for neighbouring nodes returns bool
    private static boolean checkNeighbourHasBeenSearched(List<Node> array, Node node) {
        return array.stream().anyMatch((n) -> (n.x == node.x && n.y == node.y));
    }


    // Calculate distance from current node to the target
    private double distance(int dx, int dy) {
        return Math.hypot(this.currentNode.x + dx - this.xEnd, this.currentNode.y + dy - this.yEnd); // return hypothenuse
    }

    // Add neighbouring nodes to the open list to iterate through next
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void addNeigborsToOpenList() {

        Node node;

        for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {

            for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {

                node = new Node(this.currentNode, this.currentNode.x + x, this.currentNode.y + y, this.currentNode.g, this.distance(x, y));

                // if we are not on the current node
                if ((x != 0 || y != 0) 
                    && this.currentNode.x + x >= 0 && this.currentNode.x + x < this.collisionMap[0].length // check collision map boundaries
                    && this.currentNode.y + y >= 0 && this.currentNode.y + y < this.collisionMap.length
                    && this.collisionMap[this.currentNode.y + y][this.currentNode.x + x] != -1) { // check if tile is walkable (-1)

                    // and finally check we haven't already searched the nodes
                    if(!checkNeighbourHasBeenSearched(this.openList, node) && !checkNeighbourHasBeenSearched(this.closedList, node)){
                        node.g = node.parent.g + 1.; // Horizontal/vertical cost = 1.0
                        node.g += collisionMap[this.currentNode.y + y][this.currentNode.x + x]; // add movement cost for this square


                        // Add diagonal movement cost sqrt(hor_cost² + vert_cost²) + 0.4
                        if (x != 0 && y != 0) {
                            node.g += .4;   
                        }

                        // Add the node to the List<>
                        this.openList.add(node);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        // sort in ascending order
        //Collections.sort(this.openList);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Define the size of the grid
        final int sizeOf = 1024;

        int[][] collisionMap = new int[sizeOf][];

        for(int i=0;i < sizeOf; i++) {
            // -1 = blocked
            // 0+ = cost
            collisionMap[i] = new int[sizeOf];
        }

        // set the value of the nodes
        for (int k = 0; k < sizeOf; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeOf; j++) {
                if(j == 0 && k < 100) {
                    collisionMap[k][j] = -1;
                } else if (j == 50 && k > 230) {
                    collisionMap[k][j] = -1;
                }else {
                    collisionMap[k][j] = 0;
                }

            }
        }        

        AStarPathfinding as = new AStarPathfinding(collisionMap, 103, 300);
        List<Node> path = as.findPathTo(0,0);

        if(path == null) {
            System.out.println("Unable to reach target");
        }


        // create image buffer to write output to
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(sizeOf, sizeOf, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        // Set colours
        int r = 255;
        int g = 0;
        int b = 0; 

        int colRed = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;

        r = 0;
        g = 255;
        b = 0; 

        int colGreen = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;

        r = 0;
        g = 0;
        b = 255; 

        int colBlue = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;

        r = 255;
        g = 255;
        b = 255; 

        int colWhite = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        if (path != null) {

            path.forEach((n) -> {
                System.out.print("[" + n.x + ", " + n.y + "] ");
                collisionMap[n.y][n.x] = 1;
            });

            System.out.printf("\nTotal cost: %.02f\n", path.get(path.size() - 1).g);

            for (int[] maze_row : collisionMap) {
                for (int maze_entry : maze_row) {
                    switch (maze_entry) {

                        // normal tile
                        case 0:
                            img.setRGB(j, i, colWhite);
                            break;

                        // final path
                        case 1:
                            img.setRGB(j, i, colBlue);
                            break;

                        // Object to avoid
                        case -1:
                            img.setRGB(j, i, colRed);
                            break;

                        // Any other value
                        default:
                            img.setRGB(j, i, colGreen);
                    }

                    j++;
                }
                // count j - reset as if it were a for loop
                if(i != sizeOf-1) {
                    j=0;
                }
                i++;
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        // output file
        File f = new File("aStarPath.png");

        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("i: " + i + ", j: " + j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Single Responsibility](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-2-orange/#Single_Responsibility_Principle_SRP)

your code is a *little bit*)* monolithic, you try to do all in one class

- creating a map
- calculating path
- drawing images

this makes it really hard to understand your code! it would greatly improve readability if you would split your code into proper classes

*) honestly: the whole code is just **ONE BIG** monolith

### programm flaws

you have already identified the source of your problems, it happens here

```
// get the lowest f value and add it to the closed list, f calculated when neighbours are sorted
this.currentNode = this.openList.get(0);
```

this does not work because you do not sort the list by the f-value, 
as already declared in your question. But **that part is essential** to have an **optimized path-finding algorithm**, and that is why you have performance issues.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245093/how-do-i-use-comparator-to-define-a-custom-sort-order) for some more hints on how to sort a list according to custom properties.

instead of following your heuristic you now have programmed a [Flood-Fill-Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) that will inspect all fields (untill it finds the lucky target one)

### programm flaws 2

when you expand your node (`addNeigborsToOpenList()`) and check the candidates, the algorithm says:

> if the path (g) is better than any previous, then add it

but you don't check that condition:

```
node.g = node.parent.g + 1.; // Horizontal/vertical cost = 1.0
node.g += collisionMap[this.currentNode.y + y][this.currentNode.x + x]; // add movement cost for this square

// Add diagonal movement cost sqrt(hor_cost² + vert_cost²) + 0.4
if (x != 0 && y != 0) {
    node.g += .4;   
}

// Add the node to the List <--WRONG HERE:
this.openList.add(node);
```

### summary code flaws

These bugs in your code prevent the efficent execution of your astar search, if you solve them your code will gain the desired performance.

### additional performance hints

on top of this if you would also apply the guidance from [coderodde](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/58360/coderodde) to optimize the new *flawless* code.

### other issues

some very basic issues

- use a formatter and apply the java code style rules
- apply java naming conventions (e.g. `boolean checkNeighbourHasBeenSearched()` should be renamed into `hasNeighbourHasBeenSearched()`)
- primitive obseesion - why is `collisionMap` an array of `int` - should it not be an array of `Field` where each `Field` has the attribute `isAccessable`
- why do you suppress warnings when you could use proper data types (`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`)?
- [tell - don't ask](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-4-green/#Tell_dont_ask) (instead of writing comments give your methods proper names)
- [magic numbers](https://codeburst.io/software-anti-patterns-magic-numbers-7bc484f40544)

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong data structures**

First of all, your poor efficiency is due to the fact that you use array lists for the open and closed sets. Change the open set to [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)  and your closed set to [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). In order to work, you will need to overwrite `equals`, `hashCode` and `compareTo` for your class `Node`.

If you don't mind "picking", you can find something relevant [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144376/nba-very-efficient-bidirectional-heuristic-search-algorithm-in-java-follow-u) (see AStarPathfinder.java).